# How to connect to an ec2 through SSH that is in a private subnet without using any public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am under a vpn an I do not have permission to have any public ip, public subnet, ip gateway etc. all that I have is a private subnet with an ec2 instance and a private ip. Exist a manner to connect to it through SSH?, I am reading about "direct connect" but I do not know if I am in the correct direction.

Comment: Does your VPN route traffic to that private subnet? If not, it needs to.

Comment: How can I do that, could you explain more in deep, please

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the site-to-site VPN connection from your on-premise network to AWS VPC.

After site-to-site VPN connection is done, you need to a new route in your Route table to point to the VGW.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am working on this solution, until now I am having a lot of issues with the firewall but apparently this will solve my problem